# Can MongoDB use multiple indexes in one query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

I am facing the decision to either use one collection with embedding or use 2 collections.

If I use one collection, then I only need to perform 1 query. If I use 2 collections, then I need to perform two queries. However, performing 2 questions allows me to use 2 indexes.

In light of the ability to use 2 indexes, can I expect better read performances by using 2 collections instead of embedding?

Comment: MongoDB can use [index intersection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-intersection/#index-intersection), is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple indexes in one collection. You can also create [compound-indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-compound/).

So, to answer your question, you should go with embedding if that was your only concern.